# How to achieve attach/detach like structure for oneToMany relationship?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-nova

Eg. Region and City are two models. Relations are defined as below:

**Region.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Region extends Model
{
    public function cities() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\City');
    }
}
```

---

**City.php**

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class City extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function region() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Region');
    }
}
```

Region can have multiple cities but a city can be associated with a single Region only. For this, I am having a list of cities already added but want to attach city with the region on the details page of a region just like if we have a many-to-many relationship.
How to validate and not allow to attach city to region which is already attached to any other region?

Comment: send only 'unused cities' to the details page.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a custom method on the model to achieve something like this. Here is an example of how you might want to do it

**City.php**

```
public function attachToRegion(Region $region) {
    if ($this->region) {
        throw new CityAlreadyAttachedException();
    }

    $this->update(['region_id' => $region->id]);
}
```

You would then call this within your repository/service/controller and catch the exception if the city model is already attached to the region model. For example:

```
try {
    $region = Region::first();
    $city = City::first()->attachToRegion($region);
} catch (CityAlreadyAttachedException $e) {
    // The city is already attached. Handle the error here
}
```